# Image As Head Background in Shiny With Title Overlay

Tags: css, r, shiny, styling

Can anyone provide me the CSS code that allows an image to be the background of a Shiny App header with a text/title over the image (image would be somewhat transparent). I have this but do not know enough to incorporate CSS styling.

```
headerPanel(h1("App Title", style="color: white" , img(src='tps.jpg', height=200, width=1150))),
```

Comment: Show me html structure

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
<div class="container">
  <h1>Title</h1>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
  background-image: url(http://grinmax.ru/img/ht5.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

Demo https://jsfiddle.net/6hzc54vw/

Answer (score 2):

**Try This...!**

**CSS :**

```
 header {       
   animation:zoom 10s 1 ease-out;
   background-size: cover;
   animation-fill-mode: forwards;
   background-image: url("https://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/thumbnails/image/abi_north_america_med_res_jan_15_2017_0.jpg");
   filter:grayscale(30%);
   height:100%;
}
header{
   display:flex;
   flex-direction:column;
   display:flex;
   text-align:center;
   flex-direction:column;
   justify-content:center;
   align-items:center;
}
```

**HTML :**

```
<header>
<h1 class="start0"><b>Welcome</b></h1>

<h1 class="start1"> <b>To Alive</b></h1>
    </div>  
</header>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this (with CSS embedded in the R code):

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(

    tags$head(
        tags$style(
            "
            .title 
            {
                background:url('http://images.clipartpanda.com/smiley-face-png-Smiley_Face.png');
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                background-size: 5% 90%;
            }
            "
        )
    ),

    headerPanel(
        h1("App Title", class = "title")

    ),


    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel("Sidebar panel"),
        mainPanel("Main panel")
    )
)

server <- function(input, output){

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: These are all great. Thanks everyone. Does anyone have any recommendations on books for Shiny CSS styling? I am so lost when it comes to editing the layouts.

Comment: This one works, but my background is only the size of my header text (h4), how can I change the size of the image and the image to fit the window size?

Comment: `tags$head(
    tags$style(
      "
      .title 
      {
        background:url('tps.jpg');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: 60% 200%;
    
      
      }
      "
    )
    ), 

        headerPanel(h1("App Title", class='title')),
        headerPanel(h1("App Title", style="color: white", img(src='tps.jpg', height=200, width=1150))),`